# Overriding properties in profile in multi module projects is not working properly in Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Pom A is parent of Pom B and Pom C.

Pom A has a profile sample-profile that overwrites a property <scala.version> defined in Pom A.

The default value of <scala.version> is `2.11`, the value defined in `sample-profile` for this property is is 2.12.

In dependencyManagement section of Pom A, one dependency's artifactId depends on the value of <scala.version>.

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scopt_${scala.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
```

Project C depends on scopt_${scala.version}. Project B depends on Project C.

Desired behavior is :

- run `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Psample-profile`and get Project C depend on scopt_2.12.

Actual behavior is :

When I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Psample-profile` or `mvn dependency:tree -Psample-profile` within the directory of Project B , the artifactId of Project C is `scopt_2.11` instead of `scopt_2.12`

`mvn help:effective-pom -Psample-profile` yields no trace of scopt_2.11 though.

How shall I fix this ?

**[Edit]** *- Initially, I build everything from Pom A with sample-profile (When I do so, I have the desired behavior, i.e. having scopt_2.12 as a dependency for project C). Then after doing code modifications on project B, I only need to build from Pom B (with the same sample-profile). And this is when I have the unexpected behavior (i.e. having scopt_2.11 as a dependency for project C).*

Comment: Please update the question : How do you build Project C before building Project B?

Comment: Initially, I build everything from Pom A with sample-profile (When I do so, I have the desired behavior, i.e. having scopt_2.12 as a dependency for project C). Then after doing code modifications on project B, I only need to build from Pom B (with the same sample-profile). And this is when I have the unexpected behavior (i.e. having scopt_2.11 as a dependency for project C).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the real reason but maven might try to resolve dependencies before it resolves profiles. Especially since they may affect plugin, which may extends maven (see [maven extensions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html)).

You could try this:

- Declare both versions in your `dependencyManagement`, without any profile jinx.
- In the child project (B), use `<artifactId>scopt_${scala.version}</artifactId>` as artifactId.

This may work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, using a Junit jar for convienience.

Parent pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>parent-demo</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.13.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <modules>
        <module>mod-b</module>
        <module>mod-c</module>
    </modules>


</project>
```

Project C looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mod-c</artifactId>

  <name>mod-a</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Project B looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mod-b</artifactId>

    <name>mod-a</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod-c</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

greg.clinker@lldevuk-gclinke:~/work/parent-demo/mod-b$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.essexboy:mod-b >-------------------------
[INFO] Building mod-a 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mod-b ---
[INFO] com.essexboy:mod-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.essexboy:mod-c:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO]       \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-27T09:47:47+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



greg.clinker@lldevuk-gclinke:~/work/parent-demo/mod-b$ mvn dependency:tree -Pprofile1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.essexboy:mod-b >-------------------------
[INFO] Building mod-a 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mod-b ---
[INFO] com.essexboy:mod-b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.essexboy:mod-c:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:compile
[INFO]       \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-27T09:47:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```